# Procedure: PLS - 00103 error

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have a procedure that does a transaction from a table to another. I already did the code, but it gets me this error

`Error(89,59): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then    <expoente (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_    LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between overlaps || multiset year DAY_ member    SUBMULTISET_`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Here's my code:

```
    create or replace procedure arm_inst (
    p_cod_armazem_zona in varchar2,
    p_cod_instituicao in varchar2)

is 
    qn_cg_pd number(8);
    qn_cm_pd number(8);
    qn_cp_pd number(8);
    qn_cg_ar number(8);
    qn_cm_ar number(8);
    qn_cp_ar number(8);
    estado_pd char (8);
begin
    select estado_ped
    into estado_pd
    from pedidos 
    where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

    select quantidade_az_cg, quantidade_az_cm, quantidade_az_cp
    into qn_cg_ar, qn_cm_ar, qn_cp_ar
    from armazem_zona
    where armazem_zona = p_cod_armazem_zona;    

if (estado_pd = 'Pendente') then
  select quantidade_pedida_cg, quantidade_pedida_cm, quantidade_pedida_cp
  into qn_cg_pd, qn_cm, qn_cp
    from pedidos
    where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

        if(qn_cg_pd <= qn_cg_ar) then -- verifica quantidade cabazes grandes
            update pedidos
            set estado_ped = 'Aprovado' --se e verdadeira da aprovado
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

            update armazem_zona -- faz update da tabela armazem com as 
            set qn_cg_ar = qn_cg_ar - qn_cg_pd -- quantidades
            where cod_armazem_zona = p_cod_armazem_zona;
      commit;
        else if(qn_cg_pd > qn_cg_ar)then -- se nao for verdadeira da recusado
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Recusado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
    end if;
        end if;
        if(qn_cm_pd <= qn_cm_ar)then --verifica quantidade cabazes medias
            update pedidos 
            set estado_pd = 'Aprovado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

            update armazem_zona
            set qn_cm_ar = qn_cm_ar - qn_cm_pd
            where cod_armazem_zona = p_cod_armazem_zona;

        else if(qn_cm_pd > qn_cm_ar)then-- condicao é falsa
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Recusado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
    end if;
        end if;
        if(qn_cp_pd <= qn_cp_ar) then
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Aprovado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

            update armazem_zona 
            set qn_cp_ar = qn_cp_ar - qn_cp_pd
            where cod_armazem_zona = p_cod_armazem_zona;
        else if(qn_cp_pd > qn_cp_ar) then 
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Recusado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
        end if;
    end if;

        select estado_pd 
        from pedidos
        where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
        if (estado_pd = 'Aprovado') then
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Aprovado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
        else if (estado_pf != 'Aprovado') then
            update pedidos
            set estado_pd = 'Reprovado'
            where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;
    end if;
    end if;

        elsif (dbms_output.put_line('O pedido já foi avaliado'));
        end if;
commit;
end;
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Near the end of your code:

```
select estado_pd 
from pedidos
where cod_instituicao = p_cod_instituicao;

if (estado_pd = 'Aprovado') then
```

It's missing an

```
INTO estado_pd
```

in your select statement.

Comment: In that IF I want to check if the last estado_pd = 'Aprovado' or 'Reprovado' so I can update the table with the result. Is that were the error is?

Comment: You have to add the INTO clause after your SELECT statement and before the FROM clause.

Comment: Moreover, you have other errors, as stated by Alex Poole and OracleUser.

Answer (score 0):

Line 89 seems to be this:

```
elsif (dbms_output.put_line('O pedido já foi avaliado'));
```

`elsif` requires a test; not sure if you're meant to be checking for something else there to decide whether to display that message, or if you just wanted an `else`:

```
else
  dbms_output.put_line('O pedido já foi avaliado');
end if;
```

This might be a little easier to follow with more consistent indentation...

That's the cause of the specific PLS-00103 you're asking about, but it's just the first error it reports in this case - seems like it gives up because of structural errors, before digging further into the statement syntax. As CorradoPiola noted, you're at least missing an `into` in the `select` at line 75, and there might be others that are gradually uncovered as the compiler gets further after each correction.